# Is 今日本に何時ですか correct?

Tags: particles, time, word-order

What I'm trying to say is "what time is it in Japan right now?". My main problem is if I placed 今 correctly and if I should use に or は?

Comment: に doesn't function as a locative marker (but で) because attribution is not a "static action" (which is a confusing term, I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most commonly and naturally, it should be:

> 「今日本{いまにほん}**は**何時{なんじ}ですか。」

You located 「今」 correctly, but used the wrong particle 「に」.  A comma after the 「今」 is optional.

Also common would be:

> 「日本**は今**何時ですか。」

Finally, you can only start a sentence with 「今日本**に**」 when it is followed by a verb describing a ***stative*** action as in:

・「今日本**に**います。」 ("I am in Japan now.")

・「今日本**に**住{す}んでいます」 ("I live in Japan now.")

How about 「で」, one would ask.  「で」 can be used when it is followed by an "active" (as opposed to "stative") verb.  You can say:

・「今日本**で**大学{だいがく}に行{い}っています。」 ("I am attending college in Japan now.")

・「今日本**で**プログラミングの勉強{べんきょう}をしています。」 ("I am studying computer programming in Japan now.")